# Undefined local variable or method for class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What did I miss?

```
ERROR: undefined local variable or method `feedback' for #<#<Class:0x007f66dc8dca30>:0x007f66dc8cee80>
```

Migration:

```
class CreateFeedbacks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :feedbacks do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :user
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller:

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @feedback = Feedback.all
  end

  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user])
    @feedback = @user.feedbacks.create(params[:feedback])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @feedback.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @feedback, status: :created, location: @feedback }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entily }
      end
    end
  end
```

User model:

```
has_many :feedback
```

Routes:

```
resources :feedbacks
  resources :users do
    resources :feedbacks
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it helps a lot to style your question and code correctly as well as mark your files (`routes.rb`, `controllers`, `models` correctly). Else it would be very difficult for readers to understand your question and spot issues with your code. You can refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help for the styleguide/ markdown.

Secondly, it looks like your `routes.rb` are incorrect - but again, this could be due to your formatting. Based on your question, it looks like your routes are:

```
resources :feedbacks 
    resources :users do 
        resources :feedbacks 
    end
end
```

When it should be:

```
resources: users do
    resources: feedbacks
end
```

Thirdly, your seem to have a typo in your model (`feedback` instead of `feedbacks`. That is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :feedbacks
end

class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Lastly, do add specifics and what exactly you ran that caused the error. E.g. did you run something in console, what page did you load?

Comment: Thanks you ! Just missing "s" :D